# undefined variable in php

Tags: php

I use localhost for testing and debugging sites, before making changes to the live site. Because MySQL failed in XAMPP, I had to install XAMPP from scratch.

Undefined variable $_post in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php on line 20

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php on line 20

Warning: Undefined variable $_post in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php on line 21

Warning: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php on line 21

Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1048 Column 'firstname' cannot be null in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php:29 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php(29): PDOStatement->execute(Array) #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\useraccount\registration.php on line 29

Comment: useraccount\registration.php - that doesn't sound like it's a WordPress error.

Comment: What are you doing to trigger this, trying to register a user in some web interface?